# originals indexes of sorted elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, indexing

```
arr = [1,3,2,4]

arr.sort #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like an array `[0, 2, 1, 3]` (original indexes in `arr.sort` order)

Is there a simple way to do that with Ruby 1.9.3?

thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
xs = [1, 3, 2, 4]
original_indexes = xs.map.with_index.sort.map(&:last)
#=> [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: i don't know which solution is the fastest

Comment: what is the character '&' at the end of second line ?

Comment: How would I reverse sort, i.e. values in descending order?

Comment: `original_indexes = xs.map.with_index.sort{ |a, b| b <=> a }.map(&:last)`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=[1,3,2,4]
p arr.map{|e| arr.sort.index(e)}
```

to avoid sorting each time, better is:

```
arr=[1,3,2,4]
arr_s = arr.sort
p arr.map{|e| arr_s.index(e)}
```

---

UPDATED

```
arr=[1,3,2,4]
start_time = Time.now
(1..100000).each do |i|
    arr.map{|e| arr.sort.index(e)}
end
elapsed = Time.now - start_time
p elapsed

xs = [1, 3, 2, 4]
start_time = Time.now
(1..100000).each do |i|
    xs.map.with_index.sort.map(&:last)
end
elapsed = Time.now - start_time
p elapsed
```

and got the result:

```
0.281736
0.504314
```

Comment: Note that map is O(n), then sort O(n log n) and then index another O(n).

Comment: BTW, `with_index` isn't present in 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I tested on MRI Ruby 2.2.1p85 (on both Mac and CentOS), tokland's solution return a **wrong** result:

```
xs = [8,3,2,7,5]
xs.map.with_index.sort.map(&:last)
#=> [2, 1, 4, 3, 0] # wrong
```

Yevgeniy Anfilofyev solution works but does **not** support non-unique array:

```
arr = [8,3,2,7,5]
arr_s = arr.sort
arr.map{|e| arr_s.index(e)}
#=> [4, 1, 0, 3, 2] # correct

arr = [8,3,5,2,8,8,7,5]
arr_s = arr.sort
arr.map{|e| arr_s.index(e)}
#=> [5, 1, 2, 0, 5, 5, 4, 2]
```

I come up this:

```
arr = [8,3,5,2,8,8,7,5]
index_order = []
arr.uniq.sort.each do |a|
  index_order += arr.each_index.select{|i| arr[i] == a }
end
r = []
index_order.each_with_index do |a, i|
  r[a] = i
end
r
#=> [5, 1, 2, 0, 6, 7, 4, 3]
```

Comment: How is the result `[2, 1, 4, 3, 0]` for the input array `[8, 3, 2, 7, 5]` wrong?


`a = [8,3,2,7,5]` .. `b = [a[2],a[1],a[4],a[3],a[0]]` ..`=> [2,3,5,7,8]`

Comment: There is no "wrong" solution, just a different understanding of the question: your code returns the index in the sorted array, but OP seemed to be asking about the index in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [6, 20, 12, 2, 9, 22, 17]
sorted = array.sort
indices = []
array.each do |n|
  index = (0...sorted.length).bsearch { |x| n <=> sorted[x] }
  indices << index
end
indices
```

This solution works with O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

`(0..arr.size - 1).sort_by { |i| arr[i] }`

Comment: It would be helpful to the questioner if you explained what that snippet is doing, to avoid continuing the copy-paste-programming culture this site is so infamous for promoting

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a temporary array of the same length as the original where each element is a pair:  the original array’s value and its index.

E.g for the [1, 3, 2, 4] it would be
[[1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]]

Then sort this array by element[0] and then extract element [1] for the result.

Like this:

```
def sort_indices(x)
  t = []
  i = -1
  x.map { |e| t << [e, i += 1] }
  t.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }.map{ |a| a[1] }
end

arr = [ 1, 3, 2, 4]
sort_indices(arr)
=> [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

By adding this as a method to the Array class it can be called on any array directly:

```
class Array
  def sort_indices
    t = []
    i = -1
    self.map { |e| t << [e, i += 1] }
    t.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }.map{ |a| a[1] }
  end
end

p [40, 10, 50, 62, 27].sort_indices
=>
[1, 4, 0, 2, 3]
```