# Consistent sorting across multiple arrays

Tags: ruby

I have the following data structure in Ruby (a hash where keys are strings, and values are arrays).

```
X = { "id": [2, 4, 1],  "name": ["a", "b", "c"], "time": [1, 0, 2]}
```

I would like to sort the array associated with the field "time", but I would like all other arrays to be sorted in a consistent manner. Example: after sorting, X should look like this.

```
X = {"id": [4, 2, 1], "name": ["b", "a", "c"], "time": [0, 1, 2]}
```

I solved this in a really ugly way (because I'm not sure how to do it). What I did was create a copy of time, then zip id and time, and sort it, then zip name and time_copy and sort it. Then unzip. I'm pretty sure this is an awful way to do it. Could someone else teach me a better method?

Comment: It should sort into b, a, then c?

Comment: Yeah. If you sort time, and you sort the name array in the same order you should get b, a, c.

Comment: Oh I see now. This data _really_ should be in an array at the top level, with hashes under it.  `[{id:2, name:'a', time:1}, ...]`. It will make much more sense and be much easier to work with.

Comment: I don't think those hashes are valid syntax. Is it `{"id" => [...]}` (string keys) or `{id: [...]}` (symbol keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @tokland's answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446181/originals-indexes-of-sorted-elements-in-ruby) and applying `values_at` to the result:

```
h = { id: [2, 4, 1],  name: ["a", "b", "c"], time: [1, 0, 2]}

time_indices = h[:time].each_with_index.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
h.values.each{|ar| ar.replace(ar.values_at(*time_indices))}
#=> {:id=>[4, 2, 1], :name=>["b", "a", "c"], :time=>[0, 1, 2]}
```

Comment: This does the sorting right, but it loses its structure. It's no longer a hash after the operations. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't know. I am on Ruby 1.9 and it _does_ change the values of `h`; according to the last, commented, line.

Comment: Are you sure you should use `each_with_index`? I think it should be `map.with_index`.

Comment: I take it back. This works perfectly (either with each_with_index, or with map.with_index). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should seriously consider changing your data structure from a hash of arrays to an array of hashes if the three pieces of data are supposed to belong together. Otherwise you can get into all sorts of trouble (what would happen if you accidentally made the arrays unequal lengths, for example) - indeed, as you have found, it makes sorting rather difficult.

If you are stuck with the hash as an input format, you can convert as follows

```
hash = {id: [2, 4, 1],  name: ["a", "b", "c"], time: [1, 0, 2]}
array = hash.map{|k,v| [k].product(v)}.transpose.map{|h| Hash[h]}
# => [{id: 2, name: "a", time: 1}, ...]
```

In the array of hashes format you can sort on a field extremely easily

```
array.sort_by{|h| h[:time]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as steenslag's, but I think `map.with_index` should be used.

```
permutation = X["time"].map.with_index{|*xi| xi}.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
X.values.each{|a| a.replace(a.values_at(*permutation))}
```